# Redirect User after Form Submit

Tags: php, forms, redirect, action, form-submit

> I have a PHP page with a form and after the user completes the form I would like to redirect them to a new page where they can decide their next action.

The suggestions I have seen involve changing the `Form Action` however my code already has an Action of `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>`.  I am new to PHP so perhaps I can submit the form data in an alternative method than `PHP_Self`?

Code below, thank you in advance for the help and any suggestions on simplifying my code is also welcome

```
    <div class="Form_container">
        <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" name="interactionForm">
        <hr>
        <span class="SectionHeader">Business Information</span><br>
        <hr>
        <br>
            DBA<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="DBA" ID="DBA"><br>
            Use<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="BusinessUse" ID="BusinessUse"><br>
            Street Address<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="StreetAddress" ID="StreetAddress"><br>
            City<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="City" ID="City"><br>
            State<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="State" ID="State"><br>
            Zip<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="number" min="1" max="99999" name="Zip" ID="Zip"><br>
            Number of Locations<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="number" min="1" max="99999" name="NumberOfLocations" ID="NumberOfLocations"><br>
            Size (sq ft)<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="number" min="1" max="9999999" name="LocationSize" ID="LocationSize"><br>
        <hr>
        <span class="SectionHeader">Contact Information</span><br>
        <hr>
        <br>
            Contact First Name<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="contactFirstName" ID="contactFirstName"><br>
            Contact Last Name<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="contactLastName" ID="contactLastName"><br>
            Contact Title<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="ContactTitle" ID="ContactTitle"><br>
            Contact Phone Number<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="contactPhoneNumber" placeholder="### - ### - ####" ID="contactPhoneNumber"><br>
            Contact Email<br>
            <input class="largeInput" type="text" name="contactEmail"><br>
            Initial Method of Contact<br>
            <select style='text-align:center;' class='largeInput' name='InitialContactMethod'>
                <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
                <option value="Door">Door</option>
                <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
            </select><br>
            <!-- Small Date picker --><!--Last Contact Date<br> 
            <input class="largeInput" type="date" name="lastContactDate"><br>-->
        <hr>
        <span class="SectionHeader">Showing Information</span><br>
        <hr>
        <br>
            Property<br>
            <select style='text-align:center;' class='largeInput' name='PropertyID'>
                <?php
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "usernameTest";
                    $password = "passwordTest";
                    $dbname = "databaseTest";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                    // Check connection
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }   
                    //Option Field
                    $PropertySelect = "SELECT DISTINCT PropertyName, PropertyID FROM Property ORDER BY PropertyName DESC";
                    $PropertyOptions = $conn->query($PropertySelect);

                    if ($PropertyOptions->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $PropertyOptions->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<option value='". $row["PropertyID"]. "'>" . $row["PropertyName"]. "</option><br><br>";   
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </select><br>
            Quality of Lead<br>
            <select style='text-align:center;' class='largeInput' name='QualityOfLead'>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="LOI">LOI</option>
                <option value="AtLease">At Lease</option>
                <option value="Executed">Executed</option>
            </select><br>
            Notes<br>
            <textarea name="Notes" cols="60" rows="10" maxLength="4000;"></textarea><br/>
            <!--<input type=hidden name="redirect" value="http://www.leasinglog.com/entrycomplete.php">-->


        <?php
     if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usernameTest","passwordTest","databaseTest");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
              {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }

            if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        {
            //CONTACT FIELDS
            $contactFirstName = addslashes ($_POST['contactFirstName']);
            $contactLastName = addslashes ($_POST['contactLastName']);
            $ContactTitle = addslashes ($_POST['ContactTitle']);
            $contactPhoneNumber = addslashes ($_POST['contactPhoneNumber']);
            $contactEmail = addslashes ($_POST['contactEmail']);
            $InitialContactMethod = addslashes ($_POST['InitialContactMethod']);
            //RETAILER FIELDS
            $DBA = addslashes ($_POST['DBA']);
            $BusinessUse = addslashes ($_POST['BusinessUse']);
            $StreetAddress = addslashes ($_POST['StreetAddress']);
            $City = addslashes ($_POST['City']);
            $State = addslashes ($_POST['State']);
            $Zip = addslashes ($_POST['Zip']);
            $NumberOfLocations = addslashes ($_POST['NumberOfLocations']);
            $LocationSize = addslashes ($_POST['LocationSize']);
            //INTERACTION FIELDS
            $QualityOfLead = addslashes ($_POST['QualityOfLead']);
            $Notes = addslashes ($_POST['Notes']);
            $PropertyID = addslashes ($_POST['PropertyID']);
        }
        else
        {
            //CONTACT FIELDS
            $contactFirstName = $_POST['contactFirstName'];
            $contactLastName = $_POST['contactLastName'];
            $ContactTitle = $_POST['ContactTitle'];
            $contactPhoneNumber = $_POST['contactPhoneNumber'];
            $contactEmail = $_POST['contactEmail'];
            $InitialContactMethod = $_POST['InitialContactMethod'];
            //RETAILER FIELDS
            $DBA = $_POST['DBA'];
            $BusinessUse = $_POST['BusinessUse'];
            $StreetAddress = $_POST['StreetAddress'];
            $City = $_POST['City'];
            $State = $_POST['State'];
            $Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
            $NumberOfLocations = $_POST['NumberOfLocations'];
            //INTERACTION FIELDS
            $QualityOfLead = $_POST['QualityOfLead'];
            $Notes = $_POST['Notes'];
            $PropertyID = $_POST['PropertyID'];
        }

        //Begin Contact Insert
            mysqli_query(
                $con,"INSERT INTO Contact (ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, ContactTitle, ContactPhoneNumber, contactEmail, InitialMethodOfContact, CreatedDate) 
                VALUES ('" . $contactFirstName . "','$contactLastName', '$ContactTitle', '$contactPhoneNumber', '$contactEmail', '$InitialContactMethod', NOW())");

            $LastID = mysqli_insert_id($con);

        //Begin Retailer Insert
            $ContactIDValue = mysqli_insert_id($con);//Get the PrimaryKey which was generated in the above ContactInsert Statement

            mysqli_query(
                $con,"INSERT INTO Retailer (RetailerName, BusinessUse,  StreetAddress, City, State, ZipCode, NumberOfLocations, CreatedDate, ContactID) 
                VALUES ('$DBA', '$BusinessUse', '$StreetAddress', '$City', '$State', '$Zip', '$NumberOfLocations', NOW()," . $ContactIDValue . ")");

        //Begin Interaction Insert
            $RetailerIDValue = mysqli_insert_id($con);//Get the PrimaryKey which was generated in the above ContactInsert Statement

            mysqli_query(
                $con,"INSERT INTO Interaction (QualityOfLead, PropertyID, CreatedDate, Notes, ContactID, RetailerID) 
                VALUES ('$QualityOfLead', '$PropertyID', NOW(), '$Notes'," . $ContactIDValue . ", " . $RetailerIDValue . ")");

            mysqli_close($con);
    }
        ?>
                <a href = "http://leasinglog.com/" target="_blank"><input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Finish" class="button"></a>
                <h4 style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px; font-weight:200;"><a href="dashboard.php" action="_toBlank"><u><i>Cancel</i></u></a></h4>
            </form>
            <br>
            <hr style="width:400px; height:10px;">
        </div>
```

Comment: You should move the code before any output. Then, once form data is processed make a 303 redirection wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>` means is that the current file, that is the file containt your form gets called on form submit. So, you can keep that the same  and then add the redirect code at the top of the page and trigger it if the form is submitted. Note that a header redirect must be called before any other output - html for example.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 //add any other checks such as form input values
 header('Location: http://myhost.com/mypage.php');
 exit;
}
```

or change you form action to any other .php you want to load and handle the form inputs there.

```
<form method="post" action="some_other.php" name="interactionForm">
```

**UPDATE:**

The `header()` needs to go before any output so:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
     //add any other checks such as form input values
     header('Location: http://myhost.com/mypage.php');
     exit;
    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>New Interaction</title> <!--Declare CSS and JavaScript-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RealtyCRM_Style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.resmenu.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can also update the php settings to view errors. This will tell you specifically if you're outputting data before the redirect - among other things but that would be among your first warnings. Just make sure to remove the `ini_set()` when you're done

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
         //add any other checks such as form input values
         header('Location: http://myhost.com/mypage.php');
     exit;
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm a bit lost with where to implement the `IF`..
I didn't include my FULL page code above, but the start of the form. In implementing your solution I added a `php` tag within the HTML `<head>` but that didn't redirect me as expected. The page is a `.php` but I declare `HTML<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning, full header code to follow.  If you could please guide on where specifically this if needs to go it would be appreciated

Comment: Full page head code
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
    <title>New Interaction</title>

    <!--Declare CSS and JavaScript-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RealtyCRM_Style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.resmenu.min.js"></script>
  <?php
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //add any other checks such as form input values
    header('Location: http://google.com');
  }?>

</head>`

Comment: Still not totally clear on how notifications work but I've updated my answer . . .

Comment: Thank you very much! Still learning, but this is great functionality to have in my toolbelt